# Why are auth rule changes not considered configuration changes by Amplify pull?

Tags: aws-amplify

Recently, I changed the access rules for my data model in AWS Amplify Console and then deployed them, but when I executed a subsequent `amplify pull` the pre and post pull status indicated "no changes" for any of my Amplify functionality, even though the relevant files were updated as expected; for example rules changing from

```js
rules: [{allow: public}])
```

to

```js
rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: owner}, {allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["Testers"], operations: [read, create, update]}])
```

Why is this not considered a change by `amplify pull`, even though it is `amplify pull` that is responsible for applying them?

Comment: What rules are these? For GraphQL?

Comment: Try pulling the backend after running `amplify gql-compile` on your local Amplify app.

Comment: If you want to apply them, you need to use amplify push command instead of amplify pull

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee Not sure what you mean. I made the changes in the console and then pulled.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary For the data model: "Data" in Amplify Studio.